Having trouble implementing Tabarview and Bottom navigation bar in my home page in Flutter/Dart
I am trying to implement both Tabbarview and Bottom navigation bar in my home page but I can't figure it out. I am returning a DefaultTabController I have a scaffold as its child with an Appbar in the scaffold having a bottom TabBar and in the body of that scaffold the code to show the different tab pages "New Post", "For You". But I also need a bottom navigation to switch to other pages like Home, Profile, Etc and the scaffold's body cannot take a second argument for the navigation bar since it already has the tabbar.
The scaffold has an APPBAR with a bottom TABBAR like this
bottom: TabBar(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      labelColor: logoBlue,
      unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,

      // TABS
      tabs: const[
        Tab(text: "New",),
        Tab(text: "Recommended",),
        Tab(text: "For You"),

      ],
     ),
    ),

And the scaffold has a Body like this
body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Posts(Provider.newPosts),
            Posts(Provider.recPosts),
            Posts(Provider.forYouPosts),

          ],

        ),

Now I need to add this to the body to control the Bottom Navigation Bar too
Center(child: WidgetList[wIndex],)


Scaffold constructor has a parameter bottomNavigationBar.


Wrap the entire page in a StatefulWidget to manage the index of
the BottomNavigationBar
Use the DefaultTabController for TabBar and TabBarView.
Use a conditional layout in the body of the Scaffold to
switch between the TabBarView and other BottomNavigationBar
pages based on the current selected index of the
BottomNavigationBar.

plz verify this code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      int _bottomNavIndex = 0;
    
      final List<Widget> _bottomNavPages = [
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Posts'),
              bottom: const TabBar(
                dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                indicatorColor: Colors.orange,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: "New"),
                  Tab(text: "Recommended"),
                  Tab(text: "For You"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: const TabBarView(
              children: [
                Center(child: Text("New Posts")),
                Center(child: Text("Recommended Posts")),
                Center(child: Text("For You Posts")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Center(child: Text("Home Page")),
        const Center(child: Text("Profile Page")),
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: _bottomNavPages[_bottomNavIndex], 
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _bottomNavIndex = index;
              });
            },
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                  label: 'Posts',
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'Home',
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  label: 'Profile',
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

I HOPE THIS IS HELP YOU. THANK YOU :)
